# NoReverseMatch from url tag inside include tag

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

I am trying to render a link inside an include html template with the url tag.
I have done this before and usually it works, but for some reason this time I can't make it.

I get a NoReverseMatch Error and suspect its because Django tries to load the url tag first but my object isn't ready, so the pk is empty. I believe that because it takes a moment until the dynamic data loads, while the static is already loaded.

The url works if I set pk to a fixed number, but I would like it to change dynamically.

Error:

```
Reverse for 'transaction' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['en/budget/account\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/$']
```

Relevant urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name='budgetapp'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('account/<int:pk>/', views.transaction, name='transaction'),
    path('account/', views.account, name='account'),
    ]
```

Relevant views:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required, user_passes_test
from .models import *
from .forms import *

def index(request):
    context = {}
    context['accounts'] = Account.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return render(request, 'budgetapp/index.html', context)

def account(request):
    context = {}
    context['account'] = get_object_or_404(Account, pk = request.POST['accountPk'])
    return render(request, 'budgetapp/account.html', context)

def transaction(request, pk):
    context = {}
    context['account'] = get_object_or_404(Account, pk = pk)
    return render(request, 'budgetapp/addTransaction.html', context)
```

index.html:

```
{% csrf_token %}
    <h1>Personal Budget</h1>
    <br />
    <p>
        <label for="accountSelector">Account:</label>
        <select required = "" id="accountSelector">
            {% for account in accounts %}
                <option value="{{account.pk}}">{{account}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </p>
    <hr />
    {% include 'budgetapp/account.html' %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        reload();
    });
    $("#accountSelector").change(function () {
        reload();
    });
    function reload() {
        var dictionary = {}
        dictionary['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
        dictionary['accountPk'] = $('#accountSelector').val();

        $('#accountDiv').load("account/", dictionary);
        console.log('Changed account');
    }
</script>
```

account.html:

```
<div id="accountDiv">
    <p>
        Name: {{account.name}} &nbsp; Account balance: {{account.balance}}&ensp;<a href="{% url 'budgetapp:transaction' pk=account.pk %}">Add a transaction</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

If I change `{% url 'budgetapp:transaction' pk=account.pk %}` to `/budget/account/{{account.pk}}` it works, but that feels wrong.
I tried to provide all necessary code, but please let me know if it is to much or something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `{% url 'budgetapp:transaction' pk=account.pk %}` then `account` *must* be in the template context. This has nothing to do with your browser dynamically loading data. The entire template is rendered by the server before the response is sent to the browser.

Using `/budget/account/{{account.pk}}` won't give an error, but if you look at the rendered HTML you'll see `/budget/account/` since `{{ account.pk }}` will evaluate as `''`.

Comment: Thanks, I added an Account instance to the index view and now it is working as intended. I neglected that when the index template loads for the first time it already loads the account template, but doesn't have an Account instance.